# Unable to write y/n to proceed in the installation of a library in kaggle

Tags: python, git, jupyter-notebook, git-bash, kaggle

I want to install gmaps library in kaggle, unfortunately, when writing `!conda install -c conda-forge gmaps` the installation starts but asks me to proceed with y/n with no input to write y or n.

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /opt/conda

  added / updated specs:
    - gmaps


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    certifi-2019.11.28         |           py36_0         149 KB  conda-forge
    conda-4.8.2                |           py36_0         3.0 MB  conda-forge
    geojson-2.5.0              |             py_0          15 KB  conda-forge
    gmaps-0.9.0                |             py_0         1.7 MB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         4.9 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  geojson            conda-forge/noarch::geojson-2.5.0-py_0
  gmaps              conda-forge/noarch::gmaps-0.9.0-py_0

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  ca-certificates     pkgs/main::ca-certificates-2020.1.1-0 --> conda-forge::ca-certificates-2019.11.28-hecc5488_0
  certifi                                         pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  conda                                           pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  openssl              pkgs/main::openssl-1.0.2u-h7b6447c_0 --> conda-forge::openssl-1.0.2u-h516909a_0


Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked upon Anaconda website FAQ and there is an answer specific to this. [*You can check the article in here*](https://anaconda.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023858254-Executing-Terminal-Commands-in-Jupyter-Notebooks)

Be sure to provide `-y` to specify yes to the install prompt as you can not submit input to the commands when running.

In my example:

```
!conda install -c conda-forge gmaps -y
```